# Can I attach the username to crash reports on Hockey App?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, hockeyapp

I am currently integrating HockeyApp into my IOS project on Xamarin and I would like to be able to attach the username to the crash reports but I cant figure out how .Is it even possible ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can attach the username and other metadata to the report with the following sample:

```
    public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
    {

        var manager = BITHockeyManager.SharedHockeyManager;
        manager.Configure(AppID);
        manager.UserEmail = "user@contoso.com";
        manager.UserId = "UserID";
        manager.UserName = "UserName";
        manager.DebugLogEnabled = true;
        manager.StartManager();
        manager.Authenticator.AuthenticateInstallation(); // This line is obsolete in crash only builds


        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
        LoadApplication(CreateApp());

        return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
    }
```